# Setting margins, or cell spacing, between a grid of images in iTextSharp PdfPTable

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

I am trying to render a PDF with a grid of images, using iTextSharp (v5.5.10). The images will all have the same dimensions and should be evenly distributed on one page.

However, with the code mentioned below, I'm having difficulty in setting the appropriate margins, or spacing between the cells.

Visually this means that the expected result is this:

[image: expected]

The **yellow highlighted lines** are the problem where I'm getting the following result instead:

[image: actual]

Notice how there are no spaces between the images? This is based on my following code:

```cs
   public void CreateGridOfImages(string outputFilePath)
    {
        // note: these constants are in millimeters (mm), 
        // which are converted using the ToPoints() helper later on
        const float spacingBetweenCells = 7;
        const float imageWidth = 80;
        const float imageHeight = 80;
        const string[] images = new [] { "a.jpg", "b.jpg", "c.jpg" };

        using (var stream = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.B2, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);

            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);

            try
            {
                document.Open();

                var table = new PdfPTable(5);
                table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

                foreach (var imagePath in images)
                {
                    var img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagePath);
                    img.ScaleToFit(ToPoints(imageWidth), ToPoints(imageHeight));

                    var cell = new PdfPCell();

                    // THIS IS THE PROBLEM... HOW TO SET IMAGE SPACING?
                    var cellMargin = ToPoints(spacingBetweenCells);                       

                    cell.AddElement(img);

                    table.AddCell(cell);
                }

                document.Add(table);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                document.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    private float ToPoints(float millimeters)
    {
        // converts millimeters to points
        return iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(millimeters);
    }
```

Now this seems trivial. And it problably is, but I've tried several options and could none of them to work properly (or at all):

- Adding Paragraph() objects with paddings between each
- Adding Padding to PdfPCell does not seem to work for me
- Looked into custom IPdfPCellEvent samples
- Absolutely positioning the images alltogether (forgetting the PdfPTable)

My hunch is that the `IPdfPCellEvent` seems the right approach. But all the iText options and variations are simply overwhelming.

Summarized, does anyone know how can I properly **set the margins/spacing between the cells**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want to have the second table in this image: [image: grid tables]

The only way to create white spacing between cells in an iText table is to set the relevant borders to the background colour and play with the padding of the cell. My pivotal code for creating the cells is:

```
            for(int i = 0; i < nrCols* nrRows;i++) {
                var img = Image.GetInstance(imagePath);
                img.ScaleToFit(ToPoints(imageWidth), ToPoints(imageHeight));
                //Create cell
                var imageCell = new PdfPCell();
                imageCell.Image = img;
                imageCell.Border = Rectangle.BOX;
                imageCell.BorderColor = useColor? BaseColor.YELLOW : BaseColor.WHITE;

                //Play with this value to change the spacing
                imageCell.Padding = ToPoints(spacingBetweenCells/2);

                imageCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                grid.AddCell(imageCell);
            }
```

As to why adding padding to the PdfPCell didn't seem to worrk:

The reason why borders are still drawn in your example, despite

```
table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
```

Is because you never use the default cell because you create a custom one with `var cell = new PdfPCell();` and pass the custom one to `table.AddCell(cell);`. If you'd have used `table.addCell(img)`, the border would not have been there (although your padding would still not be your desired spacing, since it isn't set on the default cell).